# polygon to triangle convertion effect visibility of the mesh

Tags: c++, opengl-es, mesh, triangulation

I am using OpenGl ES to visualize a mesh which has polygons with more than 3 vertexes. I wanted to convert these polygons to triangles using following loop. In the loop I created `polygonVertexSize-2` number of triangles just by filling an OpenGL index array which refers to same vertexes in a different order and times.

```
for(int j=0;j<polygonVertexSize-2;j++)   //number of triangles
   {

    //GetPolygonVertex returns the index of a polygon Vertex 
    indices[indp+0]=Polygon->GetPolygonVertex(0); 
    indices[indp+1]=Polygon->GetPolygonVertex(1+j);
    indices[indp+2]=Polygon->GetPolygonVertex(2+j);
    indp+=3;

   }
```

Problem with this conversion is, unless I apply    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE) some parts of the meshes are not visible. Which probably means my triangulation cause surface normals to be wrong. Another thing to note is, I average a normal for a vertex using the normals of the same vertex in different triangles.

How may I solve this problem? is it a bad idea to disable culling to solve this problem?
 Here are the results with culling and without
[image][image]

Comment: In rendering surfaces doesn't have normals. Vertices has. Normals on surface are interpolated from vertices normals. So it shouldn't change. Can you attach a screenshots - with `GL_CULL_FACE` enabled and disabled? Are you sure that your polygon is convex? Otherwise your triangulation can be wrong

Comment: I added the results, I now started thinking if there is really a convex  polygon. Is there a way to investigate this programmatically? visually it is a little bit hard to see especially in small parts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with [back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling).
Part of the mesh are invisible because they are facing away from camera. `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)` is the simplest way to solve this problem but this can cause performance problems (every triangle is processed twice). But it shouldn't affect your scene.
If you want to do it "right" you have to change the winding for invisible triangles. Just swap two vertices.

```
//only for invisible triangles
indices[indp+0]=Polygon->GetPolygonVertex(0); 
indices[indp+1]=Polygon->GetPolygonVertex(2+j);
indices[indp+2]=Polygon->GetPolygonVertex(1+j);
```

Your triangulation is right if your polygon is planar and convex. You can simply check if your polygon is convex using [gift wrapping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) or just walk through vertices and compute [dot products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), if the sign of dot product changes, polygon is not convex

Comment: Just now I tried 6 different combinations of this order, and each time  different parts were missing. I will also talk with the designer if he used any concave polygons or if there is something with the normals and let you know

Comment: It's hard to tell becouse I don't know which part are separate but the model is clearly broken if you have to performs hacks to display it properly. If you're modelling it in 3rd party software it should have option to export it already triangulated